# can't refresh the data in a DIV python Django nor the page after a jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, django

Let me start by saying I have 2 variables in an HTML template(messages and users) and I have multiple buttons that when one of them is clicked it calls a jquery code that sends a post request to a Django server and it returns an update to a variable(messages)
however, it's not updating the loop, I also tried to return a new HTML page that contains the new variable updated but the jquery is not updating the whole page with the new HTML

if I can update the variable alone it would be better and if I can't do that how can I make jquery use the new HTML page
the python code i used to return the update to the varialbe messages:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        send=Message.objects.filter(from_id=request.POST.get('userId'),to_id=2)
        rec=Message.objects.filter(from_id=2,to_id=request.POST.get('userId'))
        messages=sorted(chain(rec, send),key=lambda instance: instance.id,reverse=True)
        print(messages)
        return HttpResponse(list(messages))
```

and the code i used to return new HTML template:

```
m = Message.objects.filter(to_id=2).order_by('-id')
    users = {}
    for i in m:
        if users.get(i.from_id.username) == None:
            users[i.from_id.username] = User.objects.get(id=i.from_id.id)
    users = list(users.values())
    send=Message.objects.filter(from_id=users[0].id,to_id=2)
    rec=Message.objects.filter(from_id=2,to_id=users[0].id)
    messages=sorted(chain(rec, send),key=lambda instance: instance.id,reverse=True)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        send=Message.objects.filter(from_id=request.POST.get('userId'),to_id=2)
        rec=Message.objects.filter(from_id=2,to_id=request.POST.get('userId'))
        messages=sorted(chain(rec, send),key=lambda instance: instance.id,reverse=True)
        print(messages)
        return render(request,'psych.html',{"users":users, "messages":list(messages)})
    return render(request,'psych.html',{"users":users, "messages":list(messages)})
```

the HTML code and jquery code that uses the variable and try to update it

```js
function newUser(id){
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url:'/psych.html/',
          data:{
            userId:id,
          },
          success: function(data){
            console.log(data);// the data returnd are correct and as needed
            //but i cant make it update the messages
            $('#messageDiv').load(document.URL +  ' #messageDiv');
          }
        })
    }
```

```html
{% for i in users %}
                  <li class="">
                    <button type="button" class="btn" onClick="newUser({{i.id}})">
                    <div class="d-flex bd-highlight">
                      <div class="img_cont">
                        <!-- here was an image ----------------------------------------------->
                        
                      </div>
                      <div class="user_info">
                        <span>{{i.id}}</span>
                        
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </button>
                  </li>
                  
                  {% endfor %}
<!-- The varialbe that i'm trying to update is called messages bottom -->

{% for o in messages %}
                      {% if o.to_id.id != 2 %}
                        
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-start mb-4">
                          <div class="img_cont_msg">
                          <!-- here was an image-->
                          </div>
                          <div class="msg_cotainer">
                            {{o.message}} 
                            <!-- <span class="msg_time">{{o.time}}</span> -->
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      {% else %}
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-end mb-4">
                          <div class="msg_cotainer_send">
                            {{o.message}}
                            <!-- <span class="msg_time_send">{{o.time}}</span> -->
                          </div>
                          <div class="img_cont_msg">
                                            <!-- here was an image-->
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                  {% endfor %}
```

if it helps i did it before and updated the messages from jquery but i used form and there was only 1 variable i will add the code to that too

```js
$(document).on('submit','#submitMessage', function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url:'/psych.html/',
          data:{
            message:$('#messageHolder').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[message=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),

          },
          success: function(data){
          // it work like charm here 
            $('#messageDiv').load(document.URL +  ' #messageDiv');
          }
        })
      })
```

```html
{% for o in messages %}
  {% if o.to_id.id == 2 %}
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-start mb-4">
      <div class="img_cont_msg">
        <!-- here was an image-->
      </div>
      <div class="msg_cotainer">
        {{o.message}} 
        <!-- <span class="msg_time">{{o.time}}</span> -->
      </div>
    </div>
  {% else %}
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end mb-4">
      <div class="msg_cotainer_send">
        {{o.message}}
        <!-- <span class="msg_time_send">{{o.time}}</span> -->
      </div>
      <div class="img_cont_msg">
        <!-- here was an image-->
      </div>
     </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
<form id="submitMessage" >
  {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="card-footer">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-append"></div>
          <input name="message" class="form-control type_msg" placeholder="Type your message..." id="messageHolder">
          <div class="input-group-append">
          <button type="submit" class="btn">
            <span class="input-group-text send_btn" ><i class="fas fa-location-arrow"></i></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured the problem and it was because i didn't know that

```
$("#messageDiv").load(location.href+" #messageDiv>*");
```

would make a GET request so all I did was adding the necessary data to the URL and then change the URL too(so if the client refreshed the page it would stay in the same spot) without refreshing the page and then do the command app there
if it could help anyone please look at the code below:

```
function newUser(id){
    var url = document.URL;
    url = url.split('/');
    
    url[url.length-2] = id;
    url = url.join('/');
    window.history.pushState("object or string", "my website name", url);
    $('#messageDiv').load(url +  ' #messageDiv');

}
```

sadly i don't know how to do post requst then load the page please if you know comment down bellow so someone else might get help from it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#messageDiv").load(location.href+" #messageDiv>*");
```

Comment: Hello thank you for replaying
I added my answer to the question